# Unity C# Adding Material Component to new GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i have a problem about adding Material component to my new GameObject.

Situation: I have a big cube and a bullet. After bullet touches to the big cube. Big cube will be pieced 5x5x5. This is ok. I created small cubes for that. I wanna add to these cubes colors. I know that blabla.AddComponent();
blabla.GetComponent().xxx;

I used this method so as to add Rigidbody, but i couldn't add a Material.

My code:

piece.AddComponent();

piece.GetComponent().color = Color.red;

Can you say how can i add material ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because `Material` is not a `Component`.

Rather, do the following:

```
var mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
mr.material = your material
```